# Position of form changes

Tags: html, css

I have a table that displays information about an item on the right side of the page. The table has one td that displays the description of the item. The description text amount changes depending on what item has been selected. On the left side of the page I have a form. I want this form to be positioned so that it does not move. But as the item description changes, the form repositions. Does anybody know why?

See below for images. The first image is where I want the form to be. The second image shows what happens when there is less description.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Use columns to separate the left and right content areas.  Then you won't have to worry about the content of the right column affecting the content of the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like your code may be set up strangely. You want to have a 2 column layout. Then the content from one column will not affect the other.

If this doesnt work you could always absolutely position the form using css like below:

```
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
```

If you can post the code your using it would help tremendously with my answer